# Practicality of the Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am getting pretty frustrated with the Lebesgue integral mainly because it seems highly impractical to calculate anything non-trivial. Whenever I look for a concrete calculation all I see are encomiums about how wonderful it is and then invariably the only concrete calculation is the Dirichlet function where unsurprisingly the measures are easy to calculate. When a run of the mill function is offered to be calculated ,I have seen one of two kinds of  responses:

1) The answer involves a trick that can't be generalized

2) The answer given is  " The function is Riemann integrable so just use that" i.e forget about the Lebesgue integral.

The only method I have seen that aspires to practicality is to use the monotone convergence theorem i.e get a bunch of simple functions whose limit is the function you want to integrate. Integrate them and take the limit. I have tried this for $x^2$ and I run into hard sums which are summed by guess what...help of the Riemann integral.(could be that I chose an inconvenient set of simple functions but that partly proves my point-very easy to make things complicated)

So is the Lebesgue integral mostly used in formal situations and then occasionally some highly pathological function is pulled to justify the work? Are there examples where the Lebesgue integral is of practical importance and there can be no recourse to the Riemann integral?  Highly discontinuous functions are not welcome.

Comment: You speak of practically in computation yet you're studying Lebesgue integration. (You may want to shift the focus of your studies.) What does "practical" mean in the sense you're using it here? It won't help you build a skyscraper.

Comment: @MattSamuel This quote comes to mind:  "Does anyone believe that the difference between the Lebesgue and Riemann integrals can have physical significance, and that whether say, an airplane would or would not fly could depend on this difference? If such were claimed, I should not care to fly in that plane." - Richard Hamming

Comment: The point to the Lebesgue integral is not that it's more "practical". And the point is _not_ that we can integrate more functions! The point is that the _theory_ works better.

Comment: It's llike saying you're disappointed with real numbers, because the only numbers that ever come up in practice are rational. (It's _exactly_ like that - $L^1([0,1])$ is the completion of $C([0,1])$ in a certain metric, just as the reals are the completion of the rationals.) Every number that actually gets calculated is rational - regardless, we couldn't do much without the reals.

Comment: Nah, we just like to torture students with the stupid thing. Looks like it's working ...

Comment: I must confess the answers thus far have surprised me. I am well aware the theory works better in principle, I tacitly acknowledge that when I talk about pathological functions. It seems to me rather astounding that this superior theory of integration is not to be used for integration. @DavidC.Ullrich I do not accept the analogy with real numbers. the proper analogy is if in some alternate world people praised how real numbers solved more equations and how they formed a complete field but approximating them with rationals was NP-HARD.

Comment: @Amara approximating reals with rational numbers is computationally undecidable. Most real numbers cannot be output to arbitrary precision by any computer program.

Comment: @MattSamuel I am a physics student who enjoys learning math in my free time so I do not need to shift my focus. Regardless, I expect a better answer than "shift the focus of your studies". I get the impression from the answers that I am being naive for expecting a theory of integration to help in integrating. And yes I know most real number are computationally undecidable but the ones we need we calculate to the accuracy we need there is no need for pendatry.

Comment: What you call "pedantry" is the heart and soul of modern mathematics. You're not alone among students of physics who find it a waste of time, but that's what math is. Mathematicians need every real number, even the uncomputable ones, because as you said without them we don't have a complete field.

Comment: "I do not accept the analogy with real numbers." Imagine my surprise. Your version of the proper analogy more or less shows you don't understand why the _reals_ are important. Say we like to solve equations. Of course we can't solve them exactly, but we're happy approximating the solutions to some number of decimal places. Fine.  Wouldn't it be nice to know that those equations _have_ solutions? So that there actually _is_ something we're approximating?

Comment: "I get the impression from the answers that I am being naive for expecting a theory of integration to help in integrating." Starting with that impression is perfectly reasonable, if naive. But the fact that you still seem to have that expectation, after it's been explained that that's _not_ the point, is curious. Look. Helping us integrate specific functions is _not_ the point to the Lebesgue integral. Nobody said it was.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich believe me I understand the point of real numbers but I divide concepts in mathematics between statements that are about structure like existence and uniqueness and questions of a more practical nature like given that I now know a pde has a unique solution what is it? Usually it is clear that these two areas of concern are separate, the confusion I run into with Lebesgue integration was that I thought these two different desires had actually melded.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Let me give an example from physics where same issue comes up. Quantum Discord is supposed to be better than entanglement in deciding what state are quantum or not .It succeeds where entanglement fails sometimes. It is nice to know that there is in principle a better way of determining what states are really quantum the problem is that calculating Quantum Discord is highly inefficient and can't  really be used in practice, that too is important to know but the fact that I acknowledge it does not mean I don't understand the point of Quantum Discord  I do and appreciate it.

Comment: @MattSamuel I understand the need for structural questions and answers my point about the reals is that the structural answers about the reals would ring hollow if in practice no one could approximate any one of them. I am not one of those physics students who thinks anything abstract is a waste of time. The issue of about lebesgue integration is that it is like a wonderful and powerful topological invariant that is highly inefficient to calculate. Noticing that would not be dismissive of this would be topological invariant. I understand the point now, this back and forth helped.

Comment: A historical note: French mathematicians took more than 30 years to begin to acknowledge the interest of Lebesgue's integral -- Picard's Treatise began to mention it in its last 1942 edition. Lebesgue himself in a letter said towards the end of his life that he owned his fame more to the Poles than the French. The triggering factor was the development of the theory of probability by Kolmogorov in the 30s: you need to have a sound theory of zero-mesure sets for any theory of probability to be developed and the consequences on integration cannot be cleanly laid out with Riemann's integral.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Andrew D Lewis wrote a nice [essay](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~andrew/notes/pdf/2007c.pdf) giving what he considers to be "The correct defence of the Lebesgue integral." Here is the Abstract:

It is well-known that the Lebesgue integral generalises the Riemann integral. However, as is also well-known but less frequently well-explained, this generalisation alone is not the reason why the Lebesgue integral is important and needs to be a part of the arsenal of any mathematician, pure or applied. Those who understand the correct reasons for the importance of the Lebesgue integral realise there are at least two crucial differences between the Riemann and Lebesgue theories. One is the difference between the Dominated Convergence Theorem in the two theories, and another is the completeness of the normed vector spaces of integrable functions. Here topological interpretations are provided for the differences in the Dominated Convergence Theorems, and explicit counterexamples are given which illustrate the deficiencies of the Riemann integral. Also illustrated are the deleterious consequences of the defects in the Riemann integral on Fourier transform theory if one restricts to Riemann integrable functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can very well live inside the world of the Riemann integral. As far as the dominated convergence theorem goes, there is Arzela's theorem that will do *almost* exactly the same: It allows you to exchange the limit operation with integration as long as the functions are bounded. However, the *repeated* applications of limits is where the Riemann theory fails. This is why you need the Lebesgue, Daniell, or Henstock–Kurzweil integral. As you can see, there is more than just one way to make this generalization, or to skin the proverbial cat. The Lebesgue theory was simply there first.